# Bash tab complete files in fixed directory

Tags: bash, tab-completion

How can I use bash tab completion on a fixed directory within a script? Suppose I have a directory `~/pdf` containing pdf-files. I want to make a simple script to view these files, e.g. `viewpdf`:

```
#! /bin/bash

evince $1
```

Let say I am in directory `~/foo/bar` and write `viewpdf ~/pdf/test.pdf`, I can then view the file. However, I would like to use bash tab completion on the `~/pdf` directory, such that `viewpdf t` `<tab><tab>` would produce the same result. How can this be done?

Comment: http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2

Comment: So you essentially want to prepend `~/pdf` to autocomplete results? The [Introduction to Programmable Completion](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html) section of the advanced bash scripting guide is a good reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on `jm666`'s suggestion and the link provided by `Kevin` I now got the following code to work:

```
_cmd() { 
    local cur files
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    files=$(ls ~/pdf/) 
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${files}" -- ${cur}) )
}
```

Note that `ls ~/pdf/*.pdf` does not work since it expands to pathname and not filename of each file..

Answer (score 3):

As 1st approximation, you can try next

```
_cmd() { COMPREPLY=($(ls ~/pdf/*.pdf)); }    
complete -F _cmd viewpdf
```

source it and you can use

```
viewpdf <tab> #and will get the list of pdf files from the ~/pdf
```

if you want simple pdf competition,

```
complete -f -X '!*.@(pdf|PDF)' viewpdf
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have several 100 pdf-files, so I don't want to list them. I just want enter the first three characters, and then press <tab> to get the name completed..